# Unable to retrieve the metrics "node:cluster_cpu_utilization:ratio"

Tags: kubernetes, kube-state-metrics

I initially utilized kube-state-metrics version v1.9.2 to access the metric "node:cluster_cpu_utilization:ratio." However, subsequent to upgrading kube-state-metrics to version 2.5.0, I am encountering difficulties in locating the equivalent metric for "node:cluster_cpu_utilization:ratio."

Could someone help me out to find.

Gone through the kube state metric logs and could n't find any solution.